# Direction of electric current

Tags: electric-circuits

What is the direction of flow of electric current in an electric circuit? Is it in the direction of flow of positive charge or from positive terminal to negative terminal?

Comment: This article, [The Direction Assigned to Electric Currents](https://www-spof.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/woppos.html), might be of interest?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your convention. 'Conventional current' flows in the same direction as positive charge, i.e. positive to negative. However electrons have negative charge and so actually flow from negative to positive.

Comment: There is only one convention in use.

Comment: Indeed, but when solving a problem, if you choose a direction of flow then all you need to do is change the charge of the electron.